# Sending an Email to Old Emails and New Emails

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder, marketing-cloud-connect

I want to run a journey that runs when someone's email has been updated. Is there a way to send notification to both the account's previous email as well as the newly replaced email?

Answer (score 1):

If it's an option, then you could inject the same key into two transactional journeys,  using different emails addresses.

There are multiple nice touches to this, low cost, fast sendout speed and each transactional send will update the email on all subscribers list on the fly (you could do this with normal journeys, but don't have the above perks). See email address update behavior: [SFMC Rest API Transactional Email Send or Transactional Journey or Single Send Journey?](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/367575/sfmc-rest-api-transactional-email-send-or-transactional-journey-or-single-send-j/367588#367588)

==

Be careful when designing two things to be simultaneous, though - What if one of both fails? It's not so outlandish to construct a failure scenario here.

There are multiple plausible scenarios where the confirmation to the "old" email works, but the confirmation you send to the "new" one doesn't go out - if e.g.the "new" email is already known as a hardbounce, blocked by list detective etc.

Sending / receiving only one of two planned e-mails might confuse the user (rightfully so, as you now have changed to "an invalid address" if you've already updated by this time).

So before this whole thing, consider a Double-Opt-In email to the "new" email that the recipient must confirm and break the process if nobody confirms. That way you can technically verify that the new email works before attempting a sendout there.